# g++ error signal 11 caught with makefile

Tags: makefile, g++

I am using makefiles to build .cpp source code. While building the dependencies for the specified source file,after including 14 header files,I encountered the error given below.

```
g++ ERROR:  signal 11 caught, stop processing
make.exe: *** [folder\cbd\new\debug/new.d] Error 32
```

Any help on this matter will be helpful.

Thanks and regards,
newbie_in

Comment: Could you show us the rule Make is using? And perhaps tell us how many `#include` statements that source file had, when you could last construct its dependency list without error?

Comment: the rule I am using is as below:  @$(CPP) -MM -DGENERATING_DEPENDENCIES $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< > $@

Answer (score 0):

g++ crashed, nothing wrong with makefiles.  The first thing to do, is to update your g++ to the latest version.  If that does not help, find the minimal example that reproduces the problem and report it to g++ maintainers.  Then as a temporary fix until they fix the bug, you will need to fool around with your `new.cpp` file, most likely the preprocessing lines, until the error disappears.